# How can I fix my Ruby/Rails local environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I somehow messed up my rails installation before so I need help re-installing it/fixing it. Here are the errors.

```
gem install rails -v 4.1.1
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0 (Errno::EACCES)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0 (Errno::EACCES)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2 directory.
$ echo $GEM_HOME
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
$ echo $GEM_PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/Users/at/bin:/Users/Digital/Desktop/android:/usr/share/ant/bin:/Users/Digital/Desktop/android/sdk/platform-tool:/Users/Digital/Desktop/android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/Digital/Desktop/android/sdk/tools:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/Users/at/bin:/Users/Digital/Desktop/android:/usr/share/ant/bin:/Users/Digital/Desktop/android/sdk/platform-tool:/Users/Digital/Desktop/android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/Digital/Desktop/android/sdk/tools
$ echo $RUBY_VERSION
ruby-2.1.2
$ rvm use 2.1.2
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
Warning! Executable 'ruby' missing, something went wrong with this ruby installation!
Warning! Executable 'gem' missing, something went wrong with this ruby installation!
Warning! Executable 'irb' missing, something went wrong with this ruby installation!
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0 (Errno::EACCES)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0 (Errno::EACCES)
```

Comment: please don't install rvm/rbenv under root nor use them there. If you require that you should specify some settings for bundler to keep the gem in project's folder.

Comment: @dddd1919 that command gives me "Error running './configure --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1418844250_ruby-2.1.5/configure.log
tail: /usr/local/rvm/log/1418844250_ruby-2.1.5/configure.log: No such file or directory
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation." error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I fixed it by uninstalling rvm

```
rvm implode
```

This will remove the rvm/ directory and all the rubies built within it. In order to remove the final trace of rvm, you need to remove the rvm gem, too:

```
gem uninstall rvm
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like another case of RVM problems with a global install, no? How about installing under your home directory?

https://rvm.io/rvm/install (see "Single-User Install Location: ~/.rvm/")

Also, something to consider:

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv%3F

Comment: If I did a global install by mistake. Can I still just install under my home directory?

Comment: @CodeCrack yes you can. just install it for a local user and remove all links to global rvm from `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ only got /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin: in those profiles

Comment: @CodeCrack add to `.bash_profile`: `if [ -z "$MY_RUBY_HOME" -a -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]; then
   source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm";
fi`, and reload bash session